# How to transfer large volume Elasticsearch index to another storage

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I want to clone a large volumne data in **Elasticsearch** to **HDFS**. My index grows about 1TB of data in a day. I have used Nifi by ScrollElasticsearchHTTP processor but the performance is very slow (about 32Mb in 5 minutes). I want to clone 1TB/1 days so it's too slow.

What can I do to speed things up?

What I've tried so far:

- Nifi: I have used ScrollElasticsearchHTTP.
- Logstash: I'm trying to use Logstash.

Comment: some wording, the rest should be quite clear

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is almost 12 MB per second indexing throughput. This can be achieved but that would depend on different items such as the number of shards, number of replicas, number of nodes, the size of documents, etc. It would be great if you could provide more details on your use case.